# Unions of arbitrary families

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been working on this problem but I just can't get anything that works.

Prove that if $\left \{ A_\alpha |\alpha < \kappa  \right \}$ is an arbitrary family of sets, then there exists a family of pairwise disjoint sets  $\left \{ B_\alpha |\alpha < \kappa  \right \}$ such that $\cup A_\alpha =\cup  B_\alpha$.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Consider the function

$$\varphi:\bigcup_{\alpha<\kappa}A_\alpha\to\kappa:a\mapsto\min\{\xi<\kappa:a\in A_\xi\}\;,$$

and use it to define the sets $B_\alpha$. For intuition: $\varphi(a)$ picks out the index of the first of the sets $A_\alpha$ containing $a$.

Comment: (+1) Nice! How did you come up with such a function?

Comment: @FromCuba: It’s really just a slick way of describing what you get when you throw out of $A_\alpha$ everything already covered by an earlier $A_\beta$ in order to get $B_\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on the answer of @Brian M. Scott.

The family $A_{\alpha}$ is indexed by a set $\{\alpha < \kappa \}$, let's just say it's indexed by a set. Unless I am missing something, there is nowhere stated that the set comes with a well ordering. Of course, you can well order it, using the axiom of Zermelo. After that things become like for sets indexed by $\mathbb{N}$. One defines 
$$B_{\alpha} = A_{\alpha} \backslash \cup_{\beta < \alpha} A_{\beta}$$
and notices that the $B_{\alpha}$'s are disjoint and have the same union as $A_{\alpha}$.

Disjointness is easy. Any $a \in \cup_{\alpha} A_{\alpha}$ is in some (exactly one) $B_{\alpha}$
$a \in B_{\phi(a)}$, see the answer of @Brian M. Scott: